# Why is sqlcmd not importing anything?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm trying to restore a 500MB `.sql` file to SQL Server; I've tried running the script directly from a query page, but the memory isn't enough, so I tried with the sqlcmd command as follows:

```
sqlcmd -S <my server name> -d <my dbname>-U <user> -P <password> -i <pathfile> -a 32767
```

I've also tried with the -o command, too see if the log would report something useful, but from that command I didn't get any error.

Still, my database in SQL Server is empty, without any single table.
I'm running this on a Windows 10 system.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your script is 500MB long you are probably doing something wrong. Investigate `BULK INSERT` and bcp

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SQL instance then the syntax will be like this:

```
sqlcmd -S <my server name>\instance -d <my dbname> -U <user> -P <password> -i <pathfile> -a 32767
```

Comment: I've checked the connection properties, and the instance name's field is empty, so i don't think that's the problem